# WatchKit - How to move label or image

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have added a label, image and button to the interface.storyboard.  How do you move the label and image to a new location when the button is clicked>

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelMove: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var image1: WKInterfaceImage!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonTest: WKInterfaceButton!

@IBAction func buttonClick() {

    image1. ????  // Tried image1.center and image1.frame      
}
```

If have tried image1.center and image1.frame but neither one worked on the WatchKit.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you cannot move any objects when the app is running.

Comment: Since this may not be possible I am using a temporary workaround.  Create multiple image objects.  Fill one object with the image and fill the rest of the objects with a transparent image. Use this command to load the images; image1.setImage(UIImage(named: "some_image.png")). There is a command to make the image hidden but the rest of the images move over when one image is hidden; image1.setHidden(true)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is restriction on what operations can be done on an object(as of now) in Interface Controller.

Below mentioned operations are supported at [runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CreatingtheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH4-SW1)

- Set or update data values.
- Change the visual appearance of objects that support such modifications.
- Change the size of an object.
- Change the transparency of an object.
- Show or hide an object.

> You cannot add new objects to your interface or change the order of the objects that are already there.

I guess that rules out shifting frames(which is not available also).